# Output text string in array

Tags: php, arrays

How do I print the following string in an array in PHP, only selecting the texts in lowercase:

```
{"fieldValue":[{"portfoliocategory":"Printing","portfoliocategoryid":"printing"},{"portfoliocategory":"Digitization","portfoliocategoryid":"digitization"},{"portfoliocategory":"Android App","portfoliocategoryid":"androidapp"},{"portfoliocategory":"Photography","portfoliocategoryid":"photography"},{"portfoliocategory":"Artwork","portfoliocategoryid":"artwork"}],"fieldSettings":{"autoincrement":1}}
```

Output should be:

```
<ul>
<li>printing</li>
<li>digitization</li>
<li>androidapp</li>
<li>photography</li>
<li>artwork</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks.

Comment: This begs the question... why did you retrieve the id's in the first place? You arent going to use them... And how did you get the above format, did you serialize/json encode it? You simply cant achieve what you want without reversing the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your question.

```
$input = '{"fieldValue":[{"portfoliocategory":"Printing","portfoliocategoryid":"printing"},{"portfoliocategory":"Digitization","portfoliocategoryid":"digitization"},{"portfoliocategory":"Android App","portfoliocategoryid":"androidapp"},{"portfoliocategory":"Photography","portfoliocategoryid":"photography"},{"portfoliocategory":"Artwork","portfoliocategoryid":"artwork"}],"fieldSettings":{"autoincrement":1}}';

$output = '<ul>'; // Store the output

$values = json_decode($input); // This will convert to an object

foreach ($values->fieldValue as $val) {
    $output .= '<li>'.$val->portfoliocategoryid.'</li>';
}

$output .= '</ul>';
```

$output will give you the expected results.

Comment: Works as expected. Thanks a ton Saumini.